# show user avatar only on the latest message if multiple messages are sent consecutively

Tags: javascript

I am working on a chat box where I need to show the messages of users by grouping the messages on a particular date. The grouping has been working fine so far. However, I could not show the image of the user on his/her latest message if sent consecutive messages. This is what I mean to say by the image should be shown only on the latest message

[image]

This is what I am doing

```
const messages = [
  {
    clientName: "Manoj",
    agentProfilePicture: "http://localhost/storage/profile/7610ff2a-ed7b-48e2-bbdf-43e5f84a764c.png",
    clientProfilePicture: "http://localhost/storage/contact/01a4379a-7fee-4981-8c33-785b81113ced.png",
    clientid: "aEowpB6yFz4qhMJAWRHkS",
    direction: "Incoming",
    createdAt: "2021-02-22T09:27:19.280314+00:00"
  },
  {
    clientName: "Manoj",
    agentProfilePicture: "http://localhost/storage/profile/7610ff2a-ed7b-48e2-bbdf-43e5f84a764c.png",
    clientProfilePicture: "http://localhost/storage/contact/01a4379a-7fee-4981-8c33-785b81113ced.png",
    clientid: "aEwpB6yFz4qXhMJAWRHkS",
    direction: "Incoming",
    createdAt: "2021-02-22T09:27:19.280314+00:00"
  },
  {
    clientName: "Manoj",
    agentProfilePicture: "http://localhost/storage/profile/7610ff2a-ed7b-48e2-bbdf-43e5f84a764c.png",
    clientProfilePicture: "http://localhost/storage/contact/01a4379a-7fee-4981-8c33-785b81113ced.png",
    clientid: "aEopB6yFz4qXhMJAWRHkS",
    direction: "Outgoing",
    createdAt: "2021-02-22T09:27:19.265184+00:00"

  },
  {
    clientName: "Manoj",
    agentProfilePicture: "http://localhost/storage/profile/7610ff2a-ed7b-48e2-bbdf-43e5f84a764c.png",
    clientProfilePicture: "http://localhost/storage/contact/01a4379a-7fee-4981-8c33-785b81113ced.png",
    clientid: "aEowpByFz4qXhMJAWRHkS",
    direction: "Incoming",
    createdAt: "2021-02-22T09:25:36.465466+00:00",
  },
  {
    clientName: "Manoj",
    agentProfilePicture: "http://localhost/storage/profile/7610ff2a-ed7b-48e2-bbdf-43e5f84a764c.png",
    clientProfilePicture: "http://localhost/storage/contact/01a4379a-7fee-4981-8c33-785b81113ced.png",
    clientid: "aEowpB6yFqXhMJAWRHkS",
    direction: "Incoming",
    createdAt: "2021-02-22T09:25:36.465466+00:00",
  },
  {
    clientName: "Manoj",
    agentProfilePicture: "http://localhost/storage/profile/7610ff2a-ed7b-48e2-bbdf-43e5f84a764c.png",
    clientProfilePicture: "http://localhost/storage/contact/01a4379a-7fee-4981-8c33-785b81113ced.png",
    clientid: "aEowpB6yFzqXhMJAWRHkS",
    direction: "Outgoing",
    createdAt: "2021-02-22T09:25:36.448490+00:00"
  },
  {
    clientName: "Manoj",
    agentProfilePicture: "http://localhost/storage/profile/7610ff2a-ed7b-48e2-bbdf-43e5f84a764c.png",
    clientProfilePicture: "http://localhost/storage/contact/01a4379a-7fee-4981-8c33-785b81113ced.png",
    clientid: "aEowpB6yFz4qXhMJWRHkS",
    direction: "Outgoing",
    createdAt: "2021-02-22T09:25:37.448490+00:00"
  },
  {
    clientName: "Manoj",
    agentProfilePicture: "http://localhost/storage/profile/7610ff2a-ed7b-48e2-bbdf-43e5f84a764c.png",
    clientProfilePicture: "http://localhost/storage/contact/01a4379a-7fee-4981-8c33-785b81113ced.png",
    clientid: "aEowpB6yFz4qXhMJAWRkS",
    direction: "Incoming",
    createdAt: "2021-02-19T05:45:07.131521+00:00"
  },
  {
    clientName: "Manoj",
    agentProfilePicture: "http://localhost/storage/profile/7610ff2a-ed7b-48e2-bbdf-43e5f84a764c.png",
    clientProfilePicture: "http://localhost/storage/contact/01a4379a-7fee-4981-8c33-785b81113ced.png",
    clientid: "aEowpB6yFz4qXhMJAWRHk",
    createdAt: "2021-02-19T05:45:07.109887+00:00",
    direction: "Outgoing"
  }
]

function getDateInYearsMonthDay(ts) {
  return `${new Date(ts).getFullYear()}-${new Date(ts).getMonth()}-${new Date(ts).getDay()}`;
}

function groupedChatDays(messages) {
  const senderCountInParticularDate = {};
  const receiverCountInParticularDate = {};
  const numberOfSenderMessages = 0;
  const numberOfReceiverMessages = 0;
  return messages?.reduce((acc, el) => {
    const messageDay = getDateInYearsMonthDay(el.createdAt);
    if (acc[messageDay]) {
      senderCountInParticularDate[messageDay] =
        el?.direction === 'Outgoing' ? numberOfSenderMessages + 1 : 0;
      receiverCountInParticularDate[messageDay] =
        el?.direction === 'Incoming' ? numberOfReceiverMessages + 1 : 0;
      return {
        ...acc,
        [messageDay]: acc[messageDay].concat([el]),
      };
    }
    return { ...acc, [messageDay]: [el] };
  }, {});
}

function generateChatMessages(messages) {
  const days = groupedChatDays(messages);
//   console.log('days', days)
  const sortedDays = Object.keys(days).sort((x, y) => {
    const a = new Date(x);
    const b = new Date(y);
    return a - b;
  });
const items = sortedDays.reduce((acc, date) => {
    const sortedMessages = days[date].sort((x, y) => {
      const a = new Date(x.createdAt);
      const b = new Date(y.createdAt);
      return a - b;
    });
    return acc.concat([{ type: 'day', date, id: date }, ...sortedMessages]);
  }, []);

  return items;
}

console.log('generatedChatMessages', generateChatMessages(messages))
```

Note: if the direction is outgoing it's a sender and the profile picture is `agentProfilePicture` and vice versa in this case.

Here is the jsbin as well https://jsbin.com/ciloxufisa/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

you can map over messages

```
messages.map(message, index) =>{
    const previous = messages[index - 1];  
    const showAvatar = shouldShowAvatar(previous, message)
}  

function shouldShowAvatar (previous, message){
    const isFirst = !previous;
    if(isFirst) return true; 

    const differentUser = message.clientid !== previous.clientid; 
    if(differentUser) return true;

    const hasBeenAwhile = message.createdAt.seconds > 60;   
    return hasBeenAwhile;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and solution. Do you mean to say I should map on ungrouped messages object or grouped messages object? Because, the avatar should be shown on the grouped messages exactly like in the image attached.

Comment: will work with both grouped and general adjust the code as you like

Comment: Is it okay if you can update jsbin with your code? I iterated over the result of `generateChatMessages()` and it just gives me an array of undefined. Probably I did not used it correctly. Can you help me by updating jsbin?

Comment: I am not sure where exactly should i place this code so I can have object of messages with and without images.

Comment: expected result is [true, false, true, false, true, false, true, true, true] as per UI but I am getting different one. https://jsbin.com/fobelagifo/1/edit?js,console. To see it in action on UI I have used react on sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-heyrovsky-kksr9?file=/src/data.js:0-62594

Answer (score 0):

this is for general

https://jsbin.com/hexodus/1/edit?js,console

```
**try it and customize it for grouped**
```